# Theorem + induction vs Fixpoint + destruct in Coq

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Can every property proved using `Theorem` in Coq by induction on one of the premises be refactored to a proof using `Fixpoint` where we destruct on the same premise? What is the point of having separate commands for `Theorem` and `Fixpoint`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. When you call the `induction` tactic, it's equivalent to `apply`ing an induction principle lemma (called something like `nat_ind` or `DatatypeName_ind`), and that induction principle was proved automatically by Coq using a fixpoint and a match. So if you "inline" the proof of the induction principle, you get a proof that could have been constructed by `Fixpoint` and `destruct`.

However, writing proofs manually using `Fixpoint` is a bit error prone, because it always adds a hypothesis into the context that corresponds to recursive calls, and the proof is only valid if you use the hypothesis on an argument that came out of a `destruct`. That condition is only checked at the time of the final `Qed` (you can check this using the `Guarded` command but this needs to know the recursive argument correctly in advance potentially using the `{struct x}` declaration). So if you write the proof using Fixpoint, and then call a tactic like `eauto`, the tactic may "accidentally" use the recursive argument in a non-wellfounded way. If you use `induction`, you only get inductive hypotheses for the direct subterms, so proofs constructed by tactics are always valid.